# Levy's theorem?

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to show convergence in probability imply convergence a.s. in this case?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90116/how-to-show-convergence-in-probability-imply-convergence-a-s-in-this-case)

Good evenig!  I stumbled upon this theorem:

For independent random variables $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ the following two statements are equivalent:

1. $\exists S_\infty \forall \varepsilon >0 : \lim_{n\to\infty} P(\vert S_\infty - S_n\vert>\varepsilon)=0 $
2. $\exists S_\infty : P(\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = S_\infty) = 1$

In the notation above $S_\infty$ denotes a random variable.
Unfortunately no proof of this theorem is given and i can not find any in my books or via google. The only hint : The theorem is named " Levy's theorem".

Does anyone know where I can find a proof ? I am very thankful for any suggestions.
With best regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Theorem 5.3.4 in Kai Lai Chung, *A course in probability theory*, 3rd ed., Academic Press, 2001.

Comment: Thank you for this reference. The book of Kai Lai Chung was not known to me. It seems to be a nice introductory course on probability!

Comment: *Introductory* is debatable but this is certainly an excellent book, well worth the time you might choose to spend working on it.