# Convergence of sum of independent random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Given a sequence $X_i$ of independant variables we denote $S_n$ as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$.

We know that $S_n$ converges in distribtion (weak* convergence).

Does that imply that $S_n$ converges almost surely?

When $\forall_{i}\ \mathbb{E}X_i = 0$, then, I guess, the sum sequence is a martingale and the convergence comes from definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the assumption of independence and weak convergence, we actually have almost everywhere convergence.

- We have to show that there is convergence in probability; once it will be done, we will conclude with [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90116/how-to-show-convergence-in-probability-imply-convergence-a-s-in-this-case), which is a weaker version of *Levy's Equivalence Theorem* that we are trying to prove here.
- Let $\mu_{m,n}$ the law of $\sum_{j=n+1}^mX_j$, that is, the probability measure associated to the random variable $\sum_{j=n+1}^mX_j$. By the assumption, the set $\{\mu_{m,n},m\geqslant n+1\}$ is tight. Assume that $\{S_n\}$ is not Cauchy in probability. Then we can find $\delta>0$ and construct by induction a sequence $\{(m(k),n(k)\}$ of integers such that $m(k)\geqslant n(k)+1$ and $n(k),m(k)$ increase, and $$\forall k,\quad E[\min\{1,|S_{n(k)}-S_{m(k)}|\}]>\delta.$$
- We have, *using independence*, that $\widehat{\mu_m}(t)= \widehat{\mu_n}(t)\widehat{\mu_{m,n}}(t)$, where for a probability measure $\nu$, $\widehat\nu (t):=\int_{\Bbb R}e^{itx}d\nu(x)$, the Fourier transform or the characteristic function of $\nu$. So $\widehat{\mu_{m(k),n(k)}}\to 1$ and $\mu_{m(k),n(k)}\to \delta_0$.
- By the second point, $\mu_{m(k),n(k)}(\{x,|x|\geqslant\delta\})>\frac 1{1+\delta}$ for all $k$. Portmanteau theorem yields a contradiction with third point.

---

- It works for random variables with values in separable Banach spaces. Actually, this sketch of proof is taken from an exercise in A. Araújo and E. Giné's book *[The Central Limit Theorem for Real and Banach Valued Random Variables](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047105304X)*. The third step is a bit more technical as we have to deal with characteristic functionals, which generalize characteristic functions.
- Note that we didn't use assumption about the existence of the expectation or moments of any order.

Comment: Hi Davide. I think making a clear statement at the beginning about what you're actually proving would help make this post more transparent. Cheers. :-)

Comment: How do you define $\hat \mu$ ? What does "Let $\mu_{m,n}$ the law of $\sum^m_{j=n+1}Xj$" mean? @DavideGiraudo

Comment: @Golob I've added this. Do you know what the law of a real valued random variable is?

Comment: ah, the distribution. Yes, I do. Thanks alot.