# Almost Sure convergence of sum of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, independence

Let $\{{X_{j}}\}_{1}^{\infty}$ be independent r.v.s such that $\sum E( |X_{j}|) <\infty$. How to show that $\sum X_{j}$ converges almost surely. 
Can I argue simply that for every $\epsilon>0, \exists N$ such that $\forall j,k >N, E(|X{j}-X_{k}|)<\epsilon$. Then I proceed exactly as in

[how to show convergence in probability imply convergence a.s. in this case?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90116/how-to-show-convergence-in-probability-imply-convergence-a-s-in-this-case?lq=1)

Comment: can someone come up with a proof which does not involve Ottiavani's inequality.....

Comment: is it Levy's equivalence theorem?

Comment: can you show its equivalent to Levy's equivalence theorem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a simple proof. By monotone convergence theorem:
$$
 \sum_j E|X_j| = E \big[ \sum_{j} |X_j| \big].
$$
It follows from the assumption that $E \big[ \sum_j |X_j| \big] < \infty$. Any random variable which has finite expectation should be finite almost surely. Thus, $\sum_j |X_j| < \infty$ almost surely. But absolute convergence for series implies convergence, hence $\sum_j X_j$ converges almost surely.

Comment: so $\{X_{j}\}$ need not be independent?

Comment: It doesn't seem so.

Comment: in your argument where did you use the fact of independence

Comment: I meant you don't need independence.

Comment: I have also made an edit. The last line should be $\sum_j X_j$ converges almost surely (not $\sum_j X_j < \infty$), since this is more precise.

Comment: This solves problem 7 on page 129 of Chung's "A Course in Probability Theory."