# Proving a.s. convergence by probabilistic convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Consider a sequence of random variable $\{X_n\}$. Let 
$$A_n = \sup\{|X_k - X_l|: k,l \geq n\}$$
$$B_n = \sup\{|X_k - X_n|: k \geq n\}$$

Now to prove a.s. convergence of $\{X_n\}$, I have seen in a theorem proof that $B_n \to^p 0$ is sufficient as that makes $A_n \to 0$ a.s.

My question is that is this technique useful to prove a.s. convergence. Are there many theorems where this technique is used ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are other examples, but the following one is quite classical: the almost sure convergence of the partial sums of an independent sequence with converges in probability. A proof is given [in this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90116/how-to-show-convergence-in-probability-imply-convergence-a-s-in-this-case).