# If independent r.v. converge in probability to a constant, do they converge almost surely?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, almost-everywhere, independence

I've seen several examples when a sequence of r.v. converge in probability but not almost surely, yet none of them had the sequence to be independent. Would additional conditions of independence and convergence to a constant be sufficient to ensure almost surely convergence?

Comment: What do you mean "converge in probability" ? I am curious about it

Comment: @Cardinal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability

Comment: Do you mean that each element of the *sequence* be independent, or it is a *series* of independent terms, which is converging?

Comment: @gt6989b: I mean it like the first "i" in i.i.d.

Comment: A related fact that may interest you: if a *series* $\sum_n X_n$ of independent random variables $X_n$ converges in probability, then it converges almost surely.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90116/how-to-show-convergence-in-probability-imply-convergence-a-s-in-this-case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $A_n$ be independent events with $\mathbb{P}(A_n)=1/n$, and define 
$X_n=1_{A_n}$. Then $X_n\to0$ in probability, but $X_n$ does not converge almost
everywhere.

Apply the second Borel-Cantelli lemma twice; once to the sequence $A_n$
 and also to the sequence $A_n^c$, to conclude that
$$P([X_n=1\mbox{ infinitely often}] \cap [X_n=0\mbox{ infinitely often}])=1.$$

Comment: Could you give an explicit example if such a sequence $(A_n)$?

Comment: @Leo If $(U_n)$ are i.i.d. uniform(0,1) random variables, then set $A_n=(U_n <1/n)$.