# Convergence in $L_p$ does not imply "a.s." convergence

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

I'm having a hard time understanding some examples about this that I found on stack exchange. So I'd like to ask for the simpler possible example where a sequence of random variables $\{T_n\}$ satisfies:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left(||T_n-T||^d\right)=0
$$
but not
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}||T_n-T||=0\right)=1
$$

Can someone give me a simple example where the above holds?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: My solution here gives an example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378565/if-independent-r-v-converge-in-probability-to-a-constant-do-they-converge-almo/1378606#1378606

Comment: Can you link to the other examples, so that people don't repeat them?

Comment: @NateEldredge specifically this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138043/does-convergence-in-lp-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere

Comment: I also only have proved Borel-Cantelli first lemma